# Permission denied error with PostgreSQL and Django. Giving rights to PostgreSQL user admin

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm, django-postgresql

I have Django app with PostgreSQL.

The app has those environment variables:

```
DATABASE_HOST=localhost
DATABASE_USER=admin
DATABASE_PASSWORD=admin
```

Here is psql output:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD 'admin123';
ERROR:  role "admin" already exists


postgres=# select * from USER;
 current_user
--------------
 postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# GRANT ALL privileges ON DATABASE my_db to admin;                 
GRANT
```

When I try to take something from db I get
`ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation app_rangeslot`.

So, the questions:

1) If user admin have all rights, why I get permission denied error?

2) If user admin is created, why I cannot see it?

Comment: Which django version are you using and can write the value of DATABASES

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem Django version is 1.8
`DATABASES = {
    'my_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME', 'my_dev'), 
        'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD', os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD', '')), 
        'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST', os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST', '')),  
        'PORT': '5432', 
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing 'default' key in the DATABASES dict. Your settings should be as given below:

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
      'NAME': os.getenv('DATABASE_NAME', 'my_dev'),
      'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER', 'postgres'),
      'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DATABASE_PASSWORD', ''),
      'HOST': os.getenv('DATABASE_HOST', ''),
      'PORT': '5432',
  }
}
```

Comment: No, default is occupied with another db. I have 2 db in one app. And the default db work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are connected as the postgres user

```
      'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER', 'postgres'),
```

don't you want to actually connect as the admin?

```
      'USER': os.getenv('DATABASE_USER', 'admin'),
```